# Probability of Default of Bonds

Tags: probability

I'm working on the following problem:

Suppose we have a portfolio of two bonds. Each of the bonds has an equal probability $1 − exp(−st)$ of defaulting in year $t$, $t = 1,\dots, 10$. In every one of the ten years, the probability that they do the same thing P(both default) + P(neither defaults) is three times the probability they do different things. The probability that
the portfolio survives 10 years without a single default is 14%. What (to the nearest basis point) is $s$?

What makes me confused is that there are two equations (associated with 75% and 14%) but only one unknown variable. Where am I wrong?

Comment: You aren't told that the defaults are independent.

Comment: it should be "the probability that the portfolio survives 10 years". And your comment makes sense!

Comment: Actually, the probability of agreement equalling 3 times the probability of disagreement each year yields 10 equations, one for each year, not 1. So you have 11 equations overall. Worse, if you assume that defaults are independent. The agreement/disagreement condition yields the same quadratic in the probability of defaulting for each year, which has only two solutions. Yet the given expression for that probability says it should be different every year, so there should be 10 different probabilities.